# Moving Images in a java applet using Timer class

Tags: java, timer, applet

I'm making a Poker program to play against the computer. I need to give the computer player's hand an animation for returning the cards it does not want, so I'm trying to use a Timer object to temporarily move the computer's card images to show that they are being replaced.

```
        timer1.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int j = cp.getHand().size() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {    
                    if (cp.getHand().get(j).isSelected()) {
                        deck.addCard(cp.getHand().set(j, deck.randomCard()));
                        cpCards[j].setLocation(CPWIDTHS[j], CPHEIGHT - 25);
                    }
                }
            }

        }, 2000);
            System.out.println(cp.getHand().size());
            for (int j = 0; j < cp.getHand().size(); j++)
                cpCards[j].setLocation(CPWIDTHS[j], CPHEIGHT);
```

This is the code I have, and it works fine executing the TimerTask's run method, but for some reason the for loop I have after to move the images back to their original positions does not work. Any idea why this isn't working?

P.S. cpCards is an array of JLabels containing the computer's card images

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) BTW - is this AWT or Swing?  For Swing, we would typically use a `javax.swing.Timer` that ensures that GUI updates are done on the EDT.

Comment: You should trey using a javax.Swing.Timer instead...